# Django models filter manytomany

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have two models

```
class Market(Model):
    title=models.Charfield()


class Product(Model):
    title=Models.Charfield()
    markets=ManyToMany(Market)
```

And i want to get products list in my view. And i want to get only one product for each market.
**How can it be done?**

```
product_for_each_market_list=Products.objects.filter()# should be rather simple.. but i can't figure what to do
```

Thanks.

Comment: just a hint `market.product_set.all()[0]`.

Comment: is it possible to get what i want by querying products?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how heavy this will be, but this is what you can use:

```
Products.objects.filter(markets__in=Market.objects.all()).distinct()
```